# Error while adding redirect (301) rule on Cpanel to force ssl

Tags: ssl, cpanel

I am new to server and cpanel. I have successfully purchased and installed ssl certificate on my domain. Now when I try to add redirect (301) for http to HTTPS for all traffic under cpanel its giving error " The is error in Apache rule while processing your request".

Please help

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post server related questions on server fault next time. BTW are u using shared hosting ?

Comment: Sorry, I am new. I am purchased host from inmotion hosting. Thanx for the help

Comment: Its OK, u should first contact the hosting provider or should do some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cpanel official documents says:

> If you try to setup a Dedicated SSL redirect using the cPanel steps
>   , cPanel will fail with an error message.

Its best you write your rewrite rules directly into .htaccess file under your root directory.
[See here for inmotion  hosting help page](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file)

Try this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: @Atanu, hope this help, if so don't forget to accept this answer.